# Although the transformation $t: x^2 \rightarrow x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2+1} - 1$ is not a linear transformation, is it another sort of transformation?

Tags: geometry, curves, transformation, plane-curves, geometric-transformation

Although it clearly isn't a linear transformation, is there any sort of other definite transformation that could carry us from $x^2$ to $x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2 + 1}$, such that we could test whether $t$ has it?

I'm interested in knowing whether I can get from $x^2$ to $x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} - 1$ by using, for instance, a combination of shears, projections, or a specific sort of warping, but I don't know whether there is some way to study warping.

My interest stems from the fact that affine maps are useful insofar as they can represent translations, reflections, scalings, rotations, shears and projections of geometrical objects. So, for instance, if I know that x→2x+1 is an affine transformation, I can visualize the procedure of transforming one into the other as a sum of the above mentioned transformations.. I'm wondering if there are other sorts of such transformations, and one for instance that would help in the specific case outlined above.

Comment: Other than what, and what is m? Also, why put in $x^2$, why not just have $x$?. Then your transformation would be $T: x\to \frac{{{x}^{2}}}{x+1}$. Finally, shear and projection generally concern matrices but your transformation is one dimensional?

Comment: @Paul for instance, it seems like it clearly isn't a linear transformation, so I'm wondering if there is a way to apply onto $x^2$, for instance, a series of stretches and projections, so that it would eventually be equal to $x^2+ \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} - 1$

Comment: @Paul I think a stretch would require at least a 2 dimensional plane, no?

Comment: @Paul I put $x^2$ since it looks like it's very similar to $x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2+1} -1$, and I don't know whether $x$ to $x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2+1} -1$ would have the same properties, besides $x$ alone not looking at all like said function.

Comment: Is $x \in \mathbb{R}$ ? Besides, you should give some context explaining your interest for this issue...

Comment: Replace $x^2$ with x in both sides of T then simplify. You T does not act in 2 dimensions. It would need to take a 2D vector and return a 2D vector. Your transformation turns a number into another number . As Jean Marie says, some context might show what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @JeanMarie you're right, I'll have to add more detail. My interest stems from the fact that affine maps are useful insofar as they can represent translations, reflections, scalings, rotations, shears and projections of geometrical objects. So, for instance, if I know that $x \rightarrow 2x + 1$ is an affine transformation, I can visualize the procedure of transforming one into the other as a sum of the above mentioned transformations. I'm wondering if there are other sorts of such transformations, and one for instance that would help in the specific case outlined above.

Comment: @Paul thank you, I will add these to my post

Comment: @JeanMarie for example, if I know a function is a rotation of another, I know I can apply the rotation matrix in order to transform one into the other.

Comment: You mention rotations like if $x$ is 2D. You haven't answered my question : is $x \in \mathbb{R}$ or not ?

Comment: @JeanMarie sorry, I'm trying to make myself clearer, I'm self-studying. Is a rotation impossible for $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$? I could, for instance, set $x_{old} = x_{new}cos \theta + y_{new} sin \theta$, and $y_{old} = -x_{new}sin \theta + y_{new}cos \theta$, and the resulting graph of the function would be a rotation.

Comment: The rotation in 1D are $180°$ rotation $x \to -x$ when done around the origin, or $x \to -x+2a$ when done around point $a$. I don't know your level in Math, but it looks like you want to decompose your operation into "simpler" ones. It depends very much on what you authorize as "simple" operations. For example, you could consider as "simple" operations of the type $x \to \tfrac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ called homographies.

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you very much, these were helpful to help me find resources to investigate the question further!

Comment: Those are also called Mobius transformations, if you are looking for search terms.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor thank you!